# Solve Blocking Transaction - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I would like to understand why blocking transaction occur with below use case and what is the best way to solve it. 
I have 3 tables as mentioned below.

```
CREATE TABLE Test_PJ (pno INT PRIMARY KEY, pname VARCHAR(20));

CREATE TABLE Test_US (sno INT PRIMARY KEY, sname1 VARCHAR(20), 
                      sname2 VARCHAR(20), sname3 VARCHAR(20));

CREATE TABLE Test_PS (pno INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Test_Pj (pno),
                      sno INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Test_US (sno) 
                      ON DELETE CASCADE,  psname VARCHAR(20),
                      PRIMARY KEY(pno, sno));

INSERT INTO Test_Pj VALUES(1,'PJ1');
INSERT INTO Test_Pj VALUES(2,'PJ2');

INSERT INTO Test_US VALUES(10,'US11','US12','US13');
INSERT INTO Test_US VALUES(20,'US21','US22','US23');
```

I am trying to run below transactions in following combination which eventually lead to a blocking transaction.

Combination:
 1. Open two DB sessions in on session T1 in another run T2a (*T2a gets
    blocked*)
 2. Open two DB sessions in on session T1 in another run
    T2b (*T2b gets blocked*)

```
/*-------------
Transaction - T1: START
-------------*/
BEGIN TRAN 
INSERT INTO Test_PS VALUES(1,10,'PSx');
/*-------------
Transaction - T1: PAUSE
-------------*/

/*-------------
Transaction - T2a: START
-------------*/
BEGIN TRAN
DELETE FROM test_us WHERE sname1 = 'US21';
/*-------------
Transaction - T2a: PAUSE
-------------*/

/*-------------
Transaction - T2b: START
-------------*/
BEGIN TRAN
DELETE ps FROM Test_PS ps INNER JOIN Test_US us 
  ON us.sno = ps.sno 
  WHERE sname1 = 'US21';
/*-------------
Transaction - T2b: PAUSE
-------------*/
```

Here T2a and T2b and trying to delete a record that is NOT related to the record that was inserted in T1.